# Search mutiple words using regular expression in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new to powershell. I highly appreciate any help you can provide for the below.  I have a powershell script but not being able to complete to get all the data fields from the text file.

I have a file 1.txt as below.

I am trying to extract output for "pid" and "ctl00_lblOurPrice" from the file in table format below so that I can get open this in excel. Column headings are not important. :

pid            ctl00_lblOurPrice

0070362408        $6.70

008854787666      $50.70

Currently I am only able to get pid as below. Would like to also get the price for each pid. -->

0070362408

008854787666

c:\scan\1.txt:

```
This is sentence 1.. This is sentence 1.1... This is sentence A1...
fghfdkgjdfhgfkjghfdkghfdgh gifdgjkfdghdfjghfdg
gkjfdhgfdhgfdgh
ghfghfjgh
...
href='http://example.com/viewdetails.aspx?pid=0070362408'>
This is sentence B1.. This is sentence B2... This is sentence B3...
GFGFGHHGH
HHGHGFHG
<p class="price" style="display:inline;">
ctl00_lblOurPrice=$6.70
This is sentence 1.. This is sentence 1.1... This is sentence A1...
fghfdkgjdfhgfkjghfdkghfdgh gifdgjkfdghdfjghfdg
gkjfdhgfdhgfdgh
ghfghfjgh
...
href='http://example.com/viewdetails.aspx?pid=008854787666'>
This is sentence B1.. This is sentence B2... This is sentence B3...
6GBNGH;L
887656HGFHG
<p class="price" style="display:inline;">
ctl00_lblOurPrice=$50.70
...
...
```

Current powershell script:

```
$files=Get-ChildItem c:\scan -recurse
$output_file = ‘c:\output\outdata.txt’ 
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $input_path = $file 
    $regex = ‘num=\d{1,13}’ 
    select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % {
    ($_.Value) -replace "num=","" } | Out-File $output_file -Append }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If that string is sample data, it's not lining up with your code at all.  There's no 'num=\d{1,13}' (or any 'num=' substring) in there anywhere that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you either mean `pid=\d{1,13}` in your code, or that your sample text should have read `num=` instead of `pid=`. We will go with the assumption that it is in fact supposed to be `pid`.

In that case we will turn the entire file into one long string with `-Join ""`, and then split it on "href" to create records for each site to parse against. Then we match for pid= and ending when it comes across a non-numeric character, and then we look for a dollar amount (a $ followed by numbers, followed by a period, and then two more numbers).

When we have a pair of PID/Price matches we can create an object with two properties, PID and Price, and output that. For this I will assign it to an array, to be used later. If you do not have PSv3 or higher you will have to change `[PSCustomObject][ordered]` into `New-Object PSObject -Property` but that loses the order of properties, so I like the former better and use it in my example here.

```
$files=Get-ChildItem C:\scan -recurse
$output_file = 'c:\output\outdata.csv'
$Results = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $Results += ((gc $File) -join "") -split "href" |?{$_ -match "pid=(\d+?)[^\d].*?(\$\d*?\.\d{2})"}|%{[PSCustomObject][ordered]@{"PID"=$Matches[1];"Price"=$Matches[2]}}
}

$Results | Select PID,Price | Export-Csv $output_file -NoTypeInformation
```